# Complete step-by-step example of using jQuery Mobile's "slider" widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm looking for a complete, step-by-step example of how to use [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)'s `slider` widget, because I'm having some trouble understanding how it works.

Comment: What code have you got so far, @pcharb? Paste some into your question, and let us know where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see several working sliders on http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/forms/slider/. If the *text* isn't clear enough, you could always try looking at the code...

Answer (score 1):

Although I've been developing software (C#, C++, Java, FORTRAN) for 10 years, I'm completely new to web development.  I've been struggling to learn how to use HTML5, JavaScript, PHP, JQuery together to build an app.  I guess I haven't learned enough jargon to find what I need from Google yet (at least not quickly).  Anyway, after a lot of searching I found the site below.  Most of the sites I've found do a good job of showing you how to include and configure your jquery mobile element.  This is a good site for this:

http://brooky.cc/2011/04/23/jquery-mobile-cheat-sheet/
(also, the one listed in the previous answer is a very good reference)

However, neither explains what to do once you have the slider (or other element) in your app.  This is the first one that actually shows you how to **USE** the slider ... which was my primary issue.  How do you get the values and use them in my application. This example really helped me understand how these things work.

[http://jsfiddle.net/m4ZEL](http://jsfiddle.net/m4ZEL/)

Below is an example of how to get the value on change.

```
$("#slider").change(function() {
   sVal = $(this).val();
}
```

hope it helps.